# Running a function at start of controller, angular js

Tags: angularjs

Let say you have this in your controller:

```
$scope.filterProductsByCategory = function(category){
...
}
```

I'd like to run this each time the controller is loaded.

But if I do like this:

```
$scope.filterProductsByCategory(category) 

$scope.filterProductsByCategory = function(category){
...
}
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Object #<Scope> has no method 'filterProductsByCategory'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try to put this call in the end of controller' definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript interpreter only knows about functions that it has read.  So, if you flip the definition of the function (call it after it is defined) all should be good:

```
$scope.filterProductsByCategory = function(category){
...
}

$scope.filterProductsByCategory(category)
```

However, I've found `ng-init` to be a better way to express in a controller that something will run on initialization:

HTML:

```
<div ng-init="init()"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.init = function() {

   $scope.filterProductsByCategory(category)
}

//define functions
$scope.filterProductsByCategory = function(category){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case $scope.filterProductsByCategory assignment happens after you try to use it.
So in short assign first, then use it.

On the other hand if the function is only used inside the controller I suggest you don't put it into scope.

You can do something like this:

```
(function(category){
...
}());
```

As a side note your function looks like a filter, so maybe you need to turn it into angular filter.